# How can I solve these Verilog questions?

Tags: circuit-design, verilog, logic-gates, wiring, boolean-algebra

I am new to Verilog Language. I did answer the questions below but I am not sure if my answers are correct. I would appreciate verification to my answers and any feedback if I am wrong. Also, if 3rd code for the question 2 is correct, wouldn't that be the simplest code, and if all of them are correct which one should I use? Thanks in advance. (I am not sure about the 4th code)

[image][image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is wrong. The output port is Fout, which is not used in the always block. So you don't get any logic gates, you get an error since F is not defined.

For the second questions, all the codes would give the same result in simulation and they describe the same hardware.

> How can I solve these Verilog questions?

1. Learn Logic Design.
2. Learn Verilog. Download the IEEE Verilog Language Reference Manual.
3. Design some digital circuits, write testbenches for them, simulate and synthesize them and see what you get.

There is no shortcut.

> verification to my answers

That's what testbenches are for. A synthesis tool can be used to verify that you get the hardware you want.